# It is worth pointing out vs It is worth noting

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

Im writing an article and I have already used the phrase "It is worth noting that..." If later on I use another phrase "It is also worth pointing out that..."  is it redundant?

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: If you say the same thing for "..." then it's redundant, otherwise not.  (And "point out" and "note", in the sense assumed above, mean the same thing.)

Comment: "It is worth noting" is more collaborative -- it suggests we're in this together, and I'm going to call your attention to something that will help you. "It is worth pointing out" is almost an aside to oneself as speaker, verbally confirming the value of what you're about to draw the listener's attention to. Far from redundant, I see them as saying two ever so slightly different things about the relationship between speaker and listener.

Answer (score 3):

*From a native speaker, a technical writer in business:*

If you are using an academic style of writing suitable for thesis papers and such, where long sentences show erudition, use either "It is worth noting that..." or "It is also worth pointing out that..." However, for general writing, use "**Note that...**" to simplify your sentence.

Even better, if you have something worth pointing out, you may just point it out without the introduction that serves as empty filler. Thus, "The color is key" is a better way to write "It is also worth pointing out that the color is key."

Answer (score 1):

***Redundancy of expression*** is concerned with the awkwardness that arises when you use exactly the same word or term, two or more times in close proximity.

Where you have two or more words or expressions which are different but mean roughly the same thing, one can **avoid redundancy** by alternating them.

***It is worth noting that the customer is afraid of snakes, and it should also be pointed out that the one we are intending to show him looks particularly venomous***, would be a perfectly good way of expressing the two matters.